# ReSharper Settings Grayed Out

Tags: resharper

Today I tried to made "Code Cleanup" of single file in ReSharper 6.0 (VS 2010). The Code Cleanup dialog did not show up so I tried again.

I then discovered, that the feature is grayed out and when I press hotkey for Code Cleanup, the notification area shows that the "command is not available at the moment".

Even the Code Cleanup settings are hidden. The panel where settings should be shown says that the settings are solution-specific and thus a solution needs to be opened (although it is, however).

All other solution-specific settings and features work, except for Code Cleanup.

I want to avoid re-installing ReSharper or resetting its settings, because otherwise I would need to set it up again (long and annoying work of setting all the options as before re-install).

I am afraid that backing up settings and restoring it again restores the problem as well.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you resolve this?

Comment: I'am getting the same problem on ReSharper 9 (VS 2013).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both ReSharper 7 and 8 seems to work OK.

Answer (score 1):

Suggestions:

1. Ensure that the file that you're trying to cleanup is included in your solution.
2. Try to reopen solution (close and then open again).
3. Upgrade to 6.1.1, maybe its fixed there.
4. File a bug report at http://youtrack.jetbrains.com

Comment: 1. and 2. have not helped, I will try to upgrade and eventually report the issue; thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old answer, but I found a little more insight on this. According to Jerrie Pelser [in this blog post from last year](http://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/cleanup-code-resharper-available), this may have to do with the file being part of a NuGet package. In my case, this was definitely it!

In case of link rot, basically the post mentions that ReSharper will avoid refactoring/code cleaning for files it detects were added as part of NuGet packages. This is similar to how it will not allow code cleanup for generated code.